# ExtJs Date is not displayed in Grid in Interner Explorer/ Mozilla

Tags: internet-explorer, datetime, extjs4, extjs4.1, mozilla

I'm trying to display a date column in a grid using ExtJs 4.1. 
My model is

```
   fields: [
             {name: 'MYDATE',   type: 'date'}
           ]
```

and the response I get from the server is

```
  {
   "success": true,
  "totalRows": "1",
  "data": [
           {
            "MYDATE": "2015-01-22 09:47:43"
           }
         ]
  }
```

In chrome it works

[image]

but in IE10 and Mozilla it does not.

[image]

Just to mention that this problem comes before applying renderers

[image]

[image]

I have also tried to add format in the model

```
   fields: [
             {name: 'MYDATE',   type: 'date', format : 'c'}
           ]
```

The database MSSQL has the value

```
           2015-01-22 09:47:43.590
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To specify a Date format in a model, you must use the `dateFormat` property, not `format` : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-dateFormat

Your error is caused by your server returning a date in the `Y-m-d H:i:s` format instead of the standard UTC format. Chrome and Safari will interpret this, but Firefox and IE will not.

Comment: Actually, I solved the problem by using `convert : function(value,record){return Ext.Date.parse(value, 'c');}` Obviously, there are more options to do this as you mention

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
```

[More information on formats here](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-parse)